# Snap SVG (JS) update coordinates

Tags: javascript, svg, drag

I want t drag a point (circle) around, which is working perfectly fine. The only thing I can't figure out is how do I write the updated position (the coordinates) of my point into a variable?

```js
var s = Snap("#main");    
var p1 = {x:50, y:150, new:0}; 
var p2 = {x:100, y:300};     
var radius = 10;

var circle1 = s.circle(p1.x, p1.y, radius);
var circle2 = s.circle(p2.x, p2.y, radius);
var line = s.line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
line.attr({
  stroke: "#000",
  strokeWidth: 5,
  strokeLinecap:"round"
});
var move = function(dx,dy) {
   
        this.attr({
                    // transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx, dy]
                    cx: p1.x + dx,
                    cy: p1.y + dy
                });
        line.attr({
          x1: p1.x + dx,
          y1: p1.y + dy
        });    
};
var start = function() {
        // this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local );
}
var stop = function() {
  p1.x = +line.attr('x1');
  p1.y = +line.attr('y1');  

    }

     
circle1.drag(move, start, stop); 

document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = p1.x;
```

```css
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 5px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calc"></div>     
<svg id="main"></svg>
```

The problem is, the coordinate is available to me as long as i qoutput it into the function 'move', but it seems once the function 'drag' is executed, i lose this info. How do i overcome that?

Comment: Hi Robert, It appears you have some formatting issues with your question, as there is no link to a codepen included as you seem to have intended. It would also be helpful if you could include code snippets for your  "move" and "drag" functions where your coordinate parameter is available and missing respectively.

Comment: thanks Max, i entered the code snippet to see the JS issues directly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to remember is that Javascript scalar (value) types like number are copied when they are assigned, not passed by reference like objects. As such, when you do

`document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = p1.x;`

the value is copied only one time into the `innerHTML`, not "bound" to the `p1.x`. As such, you'll need to set this *each time* your value changes:

```
var move = function(dx,dy) {
        document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = p1.x; 
        this.attr({
                    // transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx, dy]
                    cx: p1.x + dx,
                    cy: p1.y + dy
                });
        line.attr({
          x1: p1.x + dx,
          y1: p1.y + dy
        });    
};
```

Modifying your move function like this will accomplish your immediate goal. To answer the question you asked, to get these values into variables you can use in any of your function's scopes, create variables outside of the function and update them as a side effect of the move function being called:

```
var s = Snap("#main");    
var p1 = {x:50, y:150, new:0}; 
var p2 = {x:100, y:300};     
var radius = 10;
var myX = p1.x;
var myY = p1.y;

var circle1 = s.circle(p1.x, p1.y, radius);
var circle2 = s.circle(p2.x, p2.y, radius);
var line = s.line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
line.attr({
  stroke: "#000",
  strokeWidth: 5,
  strokeLinecap:"round"
});
var move = function(dx,dy) {
        //updating outer scope's values here
        myX = p1.x + dx;
        myY = p1.y + dy;
        document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = p1.x;
        this.attr({
                    // transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx, dy]
                    cx: p1.x + dx,
                    cy: p1.y + dy
                });
        line.attr({
          x1: p1.x + dx,
          y1: p1.y + dy
        });    
};
var start = function() {
        // myX and myY are available here
        // this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local );
}
var stop = function() {
  p1.x = +line.attr('x1');
  p1.y = +line.attr('y1');  

    }


circle1.drag(move, start, stop);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. So far, so good! only thing that is not working is that myX & myY get updated outside the move-function scope. I have it lik this now: var x =p1.x; ... var move = function(dx,dy) {
   x = p1.x + dx;}; But x doesn't change outside the function. here's a codepen to show what i'm talking about: http://codepen.io/x4ecro/pen/apMGRj. The problem is, that i want to calculate angles between, e.g. line1 and m_side1, which is not possible if the updated variables are not available to me outside the respective move functions.